# Can I run a jar file from shared folder of remote system just by double clicking from my system?

Tags: jar, batch-file

I shared a folder containing a .bat file which calls/run a jar file from same folder. I need to run that .bat file(present on remote system's shared folder) from my system. It run successfully if that folder is on my system but if i run the same file from shared folder of remote system it gives message "cannot access jar file."

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without checking your .bat file content, my only guess is that you might be using `java -jar foo.jar`, try to replace it with `java -jar "%~dp0foo.jar"`.